# How to assign grep information to variable Bash

Tags: macos, bash

I am trying to throw the output of a grep command into a variable, however it doesn't seem to be working. The following is the script I have:

```
#! /bin/bash
Output=$(grep -i ttl /etc/asl/com.apple.authd)
Check="> system.log mode=0640 format=bsd rotate=seq compress file_max=5M all_max=50M ttl=90
> appfirewall.log mode=0640 format=bsd rotate=utc compress file_max=5M ttl=90"
echo $Output
echo $Check
if [ "$Output" = "$Check" ]
    then
       echo "OK"
      else
    echo "FALSE"

fi
```

During the "echo $Output" nothing seems to be displayed, any ideas?

Comment: It should work. Check the output of the `grep` manually to make sure there's something there. Does the user running the script have read access to `/etc/asl/com.apple.authd`? It's normally `root` access.

Comment: What is output of `grep -i ttl /etc/asl/com.apple.authd` ?

Comment: Use `echo "$Output"` instead of `echo $Output`. Especially when your variable may contain shell meta-characters like `>`. But it's better and safer to just do it always anyway...

Comment: @twalberg: `>` would be harmless at the moment of variable expansions since metacharacters and keywords have already been parsed at this stage. Quoting is important, though, to protect from word splitting and pathname expansion.

Comment: Lurker was right I added in sudo and it fixed the issue!